# Permission Denied When Installing Packages Using Pip In Docker Container Django

Tags: python, django, docker, ubuntu, pip

I'm unable to install the package inside my docker container, please let me know how can I solve this.

Warning:

> WARNING: The directory '/home/app/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.

error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/app'
Check the permissions.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./core/ /app/
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home app && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    chown -R app:app /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

USER app

CMD ["/scripts/run.sh"]
```

command inside container:

```
pip install django-storages
```

Comment: You wouldn't usually run `pip install` inside a running container, since any changes you make that way will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Can you add the package to `requirements.txt`, rebuild the image, and recreate the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I already added the package inside the `requirements.txt` file but I'm currently in the development mode so that's not the good approach to rebuild the docker image every time when I installed any package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, I've installed the package using the root user by adding `-u 0` which tells docker to go in as root user.

```
docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user's `'/home/app'` directory either doesn't exist or has the wrong permissions.

It looks like you are passing `--no-create-home` to `adduser`, that's probably your issue.

(For others who find their way here, to create my user I was using `RUN useradd -u 1000 app` but my home directory was not being created for some reason...  Using `RUN adduser --uid 1000 --disabled-password app` worked for me instead.)